# Select the field to be added in the select and add it

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I have select with options of fields. I select the field I want to add. When I call a function, I add an object to the array. From this object you need to get the field. It turned out.

```
    $scope.addNewField = function(id, type) {
      console.log(type);
      if(type == "DD"){
        $scope.arrays.push({
                  "id":$scope.arrays.length + 1,
                  "parentId":id,
                  "type":"DD",
                  "images":[],
                  "text":[
                    {
                      "title":"",
                      "text":""
                    }
                  ],
                  "table":[]
                });

        $scope.indexarr = $scope.arrays.length - 1
              console.log($scope.arrays);

              var html='<div ng-click="selectedValue(value)">Value</div>',
                  el = document.getElementById('myID');

                  angular.element(el).append( $compile('<div class="form-group" dragula="bag-one"><label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Название</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="arrays[indexarr].text[0].text" name="title" placeholder="Название" required><p ng-show="userForm.name.$error.required && ( vm.formSubmitted || userForm.name.$touched)" class="help-block">Это обязательное поле.</p></div></div>')($scope) )


      }
      if(type == "TABLE"){
        $scope.arrays.push({
                  "id":3,
                  "parentId":id,
                  "type":"TABLE",
                  "images":[],
                  "text":[
                    {
                      "title":null,
                      "text":"Andrey For WebView"
                    }
                  ],
                  "table":[]
                });
                     $scope.indexarr = $scope.arrays.length - 1
              console.log($scope.arrays);

              var html='<div ng-click="selectedValue(value)">Value</div>',
                  el = document.getElementById('myID');

                  angular.element(el).append( $compile('<div class="form-group" dragula="bag-one"><label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Название</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="arrays[indexarr].text[0].text" name="title" placeholder="Название" required><p ng-show="userForm.name.$error.required && ( vm.formSubmitted || userForm.name.$touched)" class="help-block">Это обязательное поле.</p></div></div>')($scope) )


      }
}
```

HTML:

```
      <select ng-model="test"><option value="DD">DD</option><option value="TABLE">TABLE</option></select>
      <button type="button" ng-click="addNewField(1, test)">отправить</button>
```

I tried ng-repeat but it duplicates field ng-IF does not help.

Must be so:

-Select field

-Add field and add array in $scope.

Comment: You dont convey yourself buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. Solved the problem with the help of ng-switch

Example:

```
                  <div class="containter" dragula='"another-bag"' dragula-model='arrays'>

                <div ng-repeat="item in arrays" dragula='"bag-one"'>

                  <div ng-switch on="item.type" id="mySwitch">

                        <div ng-switch-when="DD" class="entry-photo">
                        <div class="form-group" >
                          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Название</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item.text[0].text" name="title" placeholder="Название" required>
                            <p ng-show="userForm.name.$error.required && ( vm.formSubmitted || userForm.name.$touched)" class="help-block">Это обязательное поле.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>   


                      <div ng-switch-when="TABLE" class="entry-photo">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Название</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item.text[0].text" name="title" placeholder="Название" required>
                            <p ng-show="userForm.name.$error.required && ( vm.formSubmitted || userForm.name.$touched)" class="help-block">Это обязательное поле.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div> 


                  </div>

                  </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are missing the element in your HTML to which you are trying to add the fields dynamically.

Try inserting below line somewhere in your HTML body and see if it works.

```
<div id="myID"></div>
```

Suggestion is based on below two lines from your code. Let me know how it goes.

```
el = document.getElementById('myID');
angular.element(el).append( $compile('<div class="form-group" dragula="bag-one"><label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Название</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="arrays[indexarr].text[0].text" name="title" placeholder="Название" required><p ng-show="userForm.name.$error.required && ( vm.formSubmitted || userForm.name.$touched)" class="help-block">Это обязательное поле.</p></div></div>')($scope) )
```

Comment: I have such a line where the fields are added, but the point is that if I add 2 fields of the same type, they are duplicated and they are four.

<div class="containter" id="myID" dragula='"another-bag"' dragula-model='arrays'>

Comment: Can you share the full source please? I tried making a working page with your code and it works just fine...!!